EF Core7 throws "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error when HasColumnName added
I am using EF Core 7.0.7 with .NET 8. I try to update a configuration as follow
Old
builder.Property(c => c.AddressId).IsRequired();

New
builder.Property(c => c.AddressId).IsRequired().HasColumnName("addressId");

Then I run
dotnet ef migrations add UpdateFieldName
dotnet ef database update

I get this error:

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at MySql.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MySQLMigrationsSqlGenerator.Generate(RenameColumnOperation operation, IModel model, MigrationCommandListBuilder builder)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationsSqlGenerator.<>c.<.cctor>b__82_22(MigrationsSqlGenerator g, MigrationOperation o, IModel m, MigrationCommandListBuilder b)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationsSqlGenerator.Generate(MigrationOperation operation, IModel model, MigrationCommandListBuilder builder)
at MySql.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MySQLMigrationsSqlGenerator.Generate(MigrationOperation operation, IModel model, MigrationCommandListBuilder builder)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationsSqlGenerator.Generate(IReadOnlyList`1 operations, IModel model, MigrationsSqlGenerationOptions options)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.GenerateUpSql(Migration migration, MigrationsSqlGenerationOptions options)
at MySql.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MySQLMigrator.GenerateUpSql(Migration migration, MigrationsSqlGenerationOptions options)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.<>c__DisplayClass16_2.b__2()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.


I suggest replacing Oracle's buggy provider with Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql. Oracle's ADO.NET and EF Core providers are so buggy, it's not really worth investigating this. The truly open source Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql and MySqlConnector providers are faster, more reliable, with more features and fix bugs that Oracle refuses to fix. Does the problem persist when you switch to Pomelo?

If you don't want to change provider (very big why?), check this possibly duplicate question where the same error was caused by renaming a field. The solution according to the poster was to move it and re-add it whatever that means. This suggest the MySQL provider chokes on previous data, or that it can't handle renames at all.  The bug may be fixed in the last EF Core 7 provider released by Oracle, 7.0.16
